# Google chart api - Read xml to form a org chart

Tags: google-visualization

I am using google chart for the first time now...
My requirement is to  read xml content to form a chart..
I need to pass the xml file name so that it reads value from specific tag...Following is what I hve tried so far...But no success...

XML file:(FlowChart.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Flow>
  <Node>
    <Id>AN001</Id>
    <Type>Annc</Type>
    <Description>Welcome msg</Description>
    <Next>MN001</Next>
  </Node>
  <Node>
    <Id>MN001</Id>
    <Type>Menu</Type>
    <Description>Language Selection</Description>
    <Next>AN002</Next>
  </Node>
</Flow>
```

### Script:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['orgchart']});

        $(document).ready(function(){
             $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "FlowChart.xml",
                  dataType: "xml",
                  success: xmlParser
              });
            });

        function xmlParser(xml) {
            $('#load').fadeOut();
            $(xml).find("Node").each(function () {
                title = $(this).find("Id").text();
                alert('Hi');
            });
        }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

I have used the same code without googleJSAPI and found the required result...
Please help on this...

Comment: How you parse the data is going to depend on what you want to do with it.  Can you give some details about what you want to do with the data?

Comment: I will parse through the XML to read <Id>...</Id>. Then using this value, i should display it in the first column..data.addColumn('string', 'Id');
         data.addColumn('string', 'Next');

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
    $('#load').fadeOut();

    var id, type, description, next;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Id');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Description');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Next');

    // parse the XML
    $(xml).find("Node").each(function () {
        id = $(this).find("Id").text();
        type = $(this).find("Type").text();
        description = $(this).find("Description").text();
        next = $(this).find("Next").text();
        data.addRow([id, type, description, next]);
    });

    // do something with data
}
function drawChart() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "FlowChart.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['orgchart'], callback: drawChart});
```

Comment: Thanks for ur effort. But xmlParser(xml) function is NOT invoked..I tried by placing alert()...

Comment: Is the AJAX request succeeding?

Comment: No...But the same ajax request was working, when i was not using any google apis. Is there any other way to pass xml file name to parse in js...

Comment: Post the full code you are using so I can see what might be going on.

Comment: ..That was a very fundamental mistake....jquery pluging was commented..Hence the problem...Thanks for ur help!!!... and I realy apologize for making u to spend on this silly mistake..